# Editing tooltip for more info

Tags: interface

I would like to customize the mouse-over tooltip to provide me with more detailed info about nodes and other things. Is there a relatively easy way to do this? I'm not a coder.

Comment: There is a UI group that works on things like this.  At the moment, I don't think there is an easy way for people to do this.  
I have been planning to present the idea that tooltips could be implemented as python files so they can be sent to the Text Editor for viewing.  So this way, short tips can be presented in the UI as a window but extended tips would be viewable when it is sent to the Editor.  This would also allow users to make edits to the tips and save the results in a very easy way.

Comment: @MarcClintDion that sounds like a great idea. I'll second your motion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to [compile blender from source](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender) if you want to write your own.

Once you have the source code, most tooltip text is defined somewhere in `/source/blender/makesrna/intern/`.

If you don't want to compile blender yourself, you can write your suggestions [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Proposals/UI/Tooltips).